# Asp.Net Core 2.2 In-Process Hosting Timeout IIS

Tags: amazon-web-services, iis, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.2, kestrel-http-server

I am facing timeout issue with Asp.Net Core 2.2 In-Process hosting model. I have a cshtml view which call an Api by an Ajax request. Api has a long running task normally takes 2-3 minutes to complete. After 1 minute, the ajax call becomes timeout in the browser. I have tried may ways. But no clues. Everyone is talking about out-process hosting with kestral server. But in In-Process hosting there is no Kestral server. So requestTimeout attribute in Web.Config will not help. 1 minute is consistent, So default timeout of something is 1 minute.

Update:

We are using AWS with load balance

Answer (score 2):

Finally we have identified the issue. Issue is not with IIS or In-Proc/Out-Proc hosting. issue is with AWS load balancer timeout. The default timeout of AWS load balancer is 1 minute. We have increased the value, worked fine. Posting this answer may help someone.

Comment: It helped, indeed. Thanks!